# Why is my benchmark over-estimating read throughput?

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking, solid-state-drive

I have some c# read throughput benchmarks for an application library I work on that seem suspiciously high and I'm trying to understand what I could do to make them more accurate.

I first measure how fast my test system can simply read and throw away data.  The idea is that this baseline value should approach the hardware read throughput limit and provide a sanity check on my benchmarking approach.  Here is the code for the baseline.

```cs
void ReadAndThrowAway(System.IO.FileStream stream, byte[] buf)
{
    int bytesRead;
    do {
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
    while (bytesRead == buf.Length);
}
```

Test hardware is an Apple SSD AP1024N from a 2019 16" touch-bar MacBook Pro which I have read has about a 2.8 GB/s throughput.  However, when I run the above code I get a throughput around 3.4 GB/s.  Further, when I run it multi-threaded I get throughputs over 5 GB/s.

I have suspected that this could be because the file is cached in RAM.  So to prevent caching I use a 32 GB test file.  My thinking is that complete benchmark runs should always be forced to read the file again since I only have 16 GB RAM.

Is it possible that my Apple SSD really is this fast?  Is this SSD PCIe 3.0 x 4 lanes? Is my benchmark over-reporting throughput somehow?  And if so how?

A full write up and source code can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/imagibee/Gigantor/blob/main/Docs/Benchmarks.md).

Comment: Do any of the involved components suggest they couldn't possibly be that fast? Is there something (code) that may be "optimized away" resulting in not actually measuring what you intended? Are you using benchmarkdotnet?

Comment: In the multithreaded version, do you read the same file starting at 0?

Comment: `(bytesRead == buf.Length)` - just FYI number of read bytes is not guaranteed to be equal to the requested size, to quote the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=net-7.0#system-io-stream-read(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)) - _"The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available"_

Comment: Also you have not shown how do you calculate the speed.

Comment: manufacturer says internal speed 3-3.4GB.  See details section in following : https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/memory-and-storage/memory-and-storage-hard-drives/78019080?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F&cid=us:sem|se|google|dsa_catchall|NB_DSA_Catchall|||12992692526|124891993914|dsa-1303230222144|search|Non_Brand&gclid=Cj0KCQjwz6ShBhCMARIsAH9A0qXW2rzfCf3h3AeXl2qB-iLDxEBjBf7VOYSdDauyy8dU7_5NiuR9kTIaAllEEALw_wcB

Comment: As Guru Stron points out, this code is fundamentally flawed, even though it will likely happen to work as expected on a simple sequential file read. You want `while (bytesRead != 0)`. A case where you consistently get reads that don't fill up the buffer might then need to be investigated for a potential performance problem, but this doesn't affect correctness. For sanity checking, you may also want to use an established method like `fio` or `diskspd` (depending on your OS) to compare to your own tests.

Comment: @jdweng thats a Lenovo part, speed looks like a match for my single threaded test, but how do you know that’s the ssd in my MacBook?

Comment: @Fildor, good idea about it being optimized away. I will take a look at the MSIL code and see what I can learn.

Comment: @thomas, no. I partition into 128 MB jobs. Each job does a seek to the start of its partition then starts reading.

Comment: @GuruStron the intent is to read until the end of the file is reached and then exit the loop. I calculate throughput by dividing bytes read by time using stopwatch.

Comment: Stopwatch can only give you a rough estimate. Better come up with a proper [benchmark](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)

Comment: Doesn't the speed match what you are getting as results?  I used the part number that you posted.

Comment: I ran AmorphousDiskMark and got 3.3 GB/s for sequential read.  This result agrees with my single-threaded result.  I've found several more references to this device being PCIe 3.0 x 4 lanes which would imply a 3.9 GB/s upper limit.  So under that assumption I'm still looking into what's wrong with my multi-threaded benchmark that causes it to over-estimate throughput.

Comment: @Fildor System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class uses a high resolution timer with a precision of 1/1000000000 seconds so that isn't a problem.

Comment: @jdweng yes, the speeds match but can you check that link? I was directed to a Lenovo page that said the part was no longer available.

Comment: @dynamicbutter It's not about the timer.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved.  I just realized that the test only exceeds 3.4 GB/s when I turn off file caching using F_NOCACHE. This makes sense because I'm turning it off while a large part of the 32 GB test file is still lodged in memory. So its going to stay lodged in memory since nothing is overwriting the file cache anymore. The subsequent tests are going to be faster because a big chunk of their data is now cached in memory.